# Highchart doesn't convert external image on view page into pdf?

Tags: php, codeigniter

i have convert the html data and **highcharts** into pdf but whenever i use external image it **do not convert that** **image** **into pdf**,i used following code but it only convert highcharts into pdf not images.

```
 Highcharts.getSVG = function (charts) {
    var svgArr = [],
            top = 0,
            width = 0;
    $.each(charts, function (i, chart) {
        var svg = chart.getSVG();
        svg = svg.replace('<svg', '<g transform="translate(0,' + top + ')" ');
        svg = svg.replace('</svg>', '</g>');
        top += chart.chartHeight;
        width = Math.max(width, chart.chartWidth);
        svgArr.push(svg);
    });
    return '<svg height="' + top + '" width="' + width + '" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">' + svgArr.join('') + '</svg>';
};

Highcharts.exportCharts = function (charts, options) {
    var form
    svg = Highcharts.getSVG(charts);
    // merge the options
    options = Highcharts.merge(Highcharts.getOptions().exporting, options);
    // create the form
    form = Highcharts.createElement('form', {
        method: 'post',
        action: options.url
    }, {
        display: 'none'
    }, document.body);
    // add the values
    Highcharts.each(['filename', 'type', 'width', 'svg'], function (name) {
        Highcharts.createElement('input', {
            type: 'hidden',
            name: name,
            value: {
                filename: options.filename || 'chart',
                type: options.type,
                width: options.width,
                svg: svg
            }[name]
        }, null, form);
    });

    form.submit();
    form.parentNode.removeChild(form);
};
```

Comment: please show your efforts for that(code you did)

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <style type="text/css">
        .container {
            max-width: 600px;
            min-width: 320px;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }
        #buttonrow {
            max-width: 600px;
            min-width: 320px;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        /**
         * Create a global getSVG method that takes an array of charts as an
         * argument
         */
        Highcharts.getSVG = function (charts) {
            var svgArr = [],
                top = 0,
                width = 0;

            Highcharts.each(charts, function (chart, i) {
                var svg = chart.getSVG(),
                    // Get width/height of SVG for export
                    svgWidth = +svg.match(
                        /^<svg[^>]*width\s*=\s*\"?(\d+)\"?[^>]*>/
                    )[1],
                    svgHeight = +svg.match(
                        /^<svg[^>]*height\s*=\s*\"?(\d+)\"?[^>]*>/
                    )[1];

                svg = svg.replace(
                    '<svg',
                    '<g transform="translate(' + i * svgWidth + ',' + 0 + ')" '
                );
                svg = svg.replace('</svg>', '</g>');

                top += svgHeight;
                width = Math.max(width, 2 * svgWidth);

                svgArr.push(svg);
            });

            return '<svg height="' + (top / 2) + '" width="' + width +
                '" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">' +
                svgArr.join('') + '</svg>';
        };

        /**
         * Create a global exportCharts method that takes an array of charts as an
         * argument, and exporting options as the second argument
         */
        Highcharts.exportCharts = function (charts, options) {

            // Merge the options
            options = Highcharts.merge(Highcharts.getOptions().exporting, options);

            // Post to export server
            Highcharts.post(options.url, {
                filename: options.filename || 'chart',
                type: options.type,
                width: options.width,
                svg: Highcharts.getSVG(charts)
            });
        };

        var chart1 = Highcharts.chart('container1', {

            chart: {
                height: 200,
                width: 400
            },

            title: {
                text: 'First Chart'
            },

            credits: {
                enabled: false
            },

            xAxis: {
                categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
                    'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
            },

            series: [{
                data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0,
                    135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4],
                showInLegend: false
            }],

            exporting: {
                enabled: false // hide button
            }

        });

        var chart2 = Highcharts.chart('container2', {

            chart: {
                type: 'column',
                height: 200,
                width: 400
            },

            title: {
                text: 'Second Chart'
            },

            xAxis: {
                categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
                    'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
            },

            series: [{
                data: [176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6,
                    54.4, 29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0],
                colorByPoint: true,
                showInLegend: false
            }],

            exporting: {
                enabled: false // hide button
            }

        });

        $('#export-png').click(function () {
            Highcharts.exportCharts([chart1, chart2]);
        });

        $('#export-pdf').click(function () {
            Highcharts.exportCharts([chart1, chart2], {
                type: 'application/pdf'
            });
        });
    </script>

    <div id="container1" class="container"></div>
    <div id="container2" class="container"></div>

    <div id="buttonrow">
        <button id="export-png">Export to PNG</button>
        <button id="export-pdf">Export to PDF</button>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: hi Piyush my code convert graphs into pdf but it dosen't convert image along with the graph in pdf.